# Exception in Java ee custom tags

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have never managed to use tags in Java ee, I always get an error that doesn't make much sense.

This is my jsp: index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tag" uri="/WEB-INF/mytags.tld"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <tag:hello/>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my tld: mytags.tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.2</tlib-version>
    <short-name>tag</short-name>

    <tag>
        <name>hello</name>
        <tag-class>hi.Hello</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
    </tag>

</taglib>
```

This is my class: Hello.java

```
package hi;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport;

public class Hello extends SimpleTagSupport {

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {

        JspWriter out = this.getJspContext().getOut();
        out.println("Hola");
    }
}
```

My Web.xml only has the welcome-file-list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Custom_Tags</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is my error stack:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (línea: 9, columna: 1) No se puede cargar la clase Hello
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:275)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:91)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1231)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1460)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:201)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:358)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:338)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:325)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:580)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I don't understand why it says that it cannot load the "Hello" class, if the eclipse itself gives me a Warning when I misspell the class, and removes it when I write it correctly.
I have tried everything and can not make it work

My Ecplise version is Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) and I use Apache tomcat v8.0

Comment: try clean your project and delete the target folder

Comment: I've already tried cleaning the project and still it hasn't worked, and I don't understand what you mean by deleting the target folder

Comment: I mean deleting the output class folder, if you're using maven then the folder name 'target' but if u compile using eclipse then it should be in 'bin' folder

Comment: Okay, I deleted it, but it still doesn't work. I have also tried to create new projects but the same problem persists